# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 IST 2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, datetime-parsing

I am facing `DateTimeParseException` even after giving appropriate format

```
DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDateTime.parse("Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 IST 2019", ft);
```

Please help if I am missing anything?

Comment: Might be a matter of locale. Is Tuesday called Tuesday in the language your computer is set with?

Comment: It seems you are trying to parse the return value from `Date.toString()`? If so it’s better to convert more directly, for example `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(yourDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the locale setting on your computer.
You might provide a Locale when creating the DateTimeFormatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

This will ensure that the date is always parsed right.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by your system locale not using `Mon-Sun` for week day short names, e.g. same exception will be thrown for German locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDateTime.parse("Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 IST 2019", ft);
```

The code will work if you use the matching locale e.g. US:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
LocalDateTime.parse("Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 IST 2019", ft);
```

Comment: Never set the default locale in some part of your code. That will break randomly. Use the DateTimeFormatter builder that takes a Locale as parameter